# How to add multiple model in a single view?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have 3 models. 1 model am using for the search box rest 2 I am using for display the checkbox list.

for search box I don't want Ienumerable type model but for checkbox I want Ienumerable type model

Data is coming from different controller
How can I do this in a single view?

Please give some example.

Comment: Build a "big" model which contains all those models.

Comment: you need to Use `ViewModel` https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/older-versions/mvc-music-store/mvc-music-store-part-3

Comment: Try creating **one model** containing properties for each of the **3 models** you told us about.

Answer (score 1):

Make `ViewModel` then send your `ViewModel` to view after setting properties;

```
    public class MyModel1 {}

    public class MyModel2 {}


    public class ViewModel
    {
     public MyModel1 MyModel1 {get; set;}
     public MyModel2 MyModel2 {get; set;}
    }
```

Then in your `view` after setting `@model ViewModel`
you can use any sub models you want like `@Model.MyModel1` etc

Comment: What class would you put the ViewModel function and the code above it in?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use 3 models in a view, you have to declare a "Bag" view model where you wrap all submodels that you want to use.

First, if you must create your submodels, if you haven't then you include them in the bag view model.

```
    public class FirstViewModel 
    {
      public int MyProperty { get; set; }
    }

    public class SecondViewModel 
    {
      public string MySecondProperty { get; set; }
    }

    public class ThirdViewModel 
    {
      public DateTime MyThirdProperty { get; set; }
    }

    public class BagViewModel
    {
      public FirstViewModel FirstModel { get; set; }

      public SecondViewModel SecondModel { get; set; }

      public ThirdViewModel ThirdModel{ get; set; }
    }
```

The submodels can be either view or binding models.

And in your razor view, you include the BagViewModel:

```
    @model BagViewModel
```

Then if you want to use **FirstViewModel** ( for example ), you do it with:

```
    @Model.FirstViewModel
```

Comment: I did this thing but in the search form when I write HTML.TextAreaBox(a=>a.FirstModelName) in the html.beginform It is showing the error.

Comment: According to the example, do you use:
- @Html.TextAreaBox(model => model.FirstModel.MyProperty)
or you do use
- @Html.TextAreaBox(model => model.MyProperty) ?